# How do I delete an accidentally created tag?

Tags: support, tags

While posting [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142669/illustrating-edward-nelsons-worldview-with-nonstandard-models-of-arithmetic), I meant to put the constructive-mathematics tag, but I accidentally just typed "con", thereby creating a "con" tag in MathOverflow.  How can I delete it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply remove the tag from your question, unless someone else uses the tag it will be removed in 24 hours. Here is a very similar question from meta.SO: [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)

More details on pruning of low-usage tags:

- The process removing  tags having no questions is running once in 24 hours, see [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)
- The process removing tag containing only one question is run once in a month and it removes tags that are at least 6 months old, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418) on meta.SO. The exception is that single occurrence tags *which have a tag-wiki* [are not removed by this proces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).