# Delete the tag paperjs

Tags: support

How can we delete a tag, for example the tag paperjs? I tried to go the page for paperjs, but I didn't see a suitable option.

Comment: See [How do I delete an accidentally created tag?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/844/how-do-i-delete-an-accidentally-created-tag) In short, if the tag is removed from all questions, you do not need to do anything else. Simply leave it to the tag removal script which removes tags with zero questions once in 24 hours.