# Could there be a warning when a new tag is created?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, warnings

It is rather easy to make a typo and create a new tag by mistake without even noticing it.<sup>1</sup> Could we have a warning saying that the user is creating a new tag so that users can notice such mistakes more easily?

This was implemented a few years ago, see: [Warning or confirmation on new tag creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62591).

[image: warning]

As far as I can tell, this feature is not enabled on MathOverflow (or at least [it was not in September](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2017/9/19)). Could moderators request this from Stack Exchange staff also on this site (both main site and meta)? On Mathematics site, this feature exists since 2015: [Warning for new tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11140#21749).

Notice that this is different from warnings which are used for existing tags: [Tag warnings on MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2798).

<sup>1</sup>It happened to me [at least once](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=40097715#40097715). The posts [How do I delete an accidentally created tag?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/844) and [Delete the tag paperjs](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2932) confirm that this occasionally happens to other users, too. I would guess that most likely the tags [fa.functional](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=40249573#40249573) and [gfractals](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42212966#42212966) were also created by mistake. A few more examples:
[ag.algebraic-topology](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/87045/revisions),
[asymtotics](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/82269/revisions),
[represetnation-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/94269/revisions),
[a.g.algebraic](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/106349/revisions),
[complex-gemetry](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/120528/revisions),
[oc.optimization-contro](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/124631/revisions),
[localy-trivial](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/163664/revisions),
[nt.number-rheory](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/177206/revisions),
[ac and ra](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/268453/revisions),
[dicrete-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/288627/revisions).

Comment: Why not separate tag use and tag creation? -- Is there really a need to allow implicitly creating new tags when tagging a question?

Comment: @StefanKohl What I suggested about is already implemented - the only thing to be done is to switch this feature on also for this particular site. What you suggest is something which would have to be implemented first. If you really think something like that is a reasonable idea, you might post it as a new feature request - either here or on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: I'll get back to you on this issue within a few days, Martin. Seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: I've sent a message to the SE Community Team about this now.

Comment: Martin, thanks for suggesting this very useful feature. Since it's enabled, I had it maybe 5-6 times: precisely in a post I click "edit tags" and type, for instance, "gt", and what happened is that the cursor is put automatically at the end of the list of the question's tags, only after I typed "g". This resulted in changing, say, "set-theory" to "gset-theory". But my eyes weren't on the tag set-theory so it was unnoticed; I just retyped "gt" instead of "t", and in this way I added the new tag while adding a typo in another tag. Now this results in the warning and it's great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just received a message from the Stack Overflow Team that the Warning pop-up for new tags has been enabled.