# Removal of the "symplectic" tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

There is a [symplectic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/symplectic) tag on MO that currently contains just two questions. The first question so tagged dates from March 26 2017, so this makes this tag at least 1 year and 4 months old. I believe that this usage frequence shows that the tag is not really needed. I suggest to remove it and retag the two questions with [sg.symplectic-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/sg.symplectic-geometry). It is hard to imagine a case covered by the former but not by the latter tag.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that there are also some other "symplectic" tags: 
([tag:symplectic-topology]), 
([tag:holomorphic-symplectic]) and
([tag:symplectic-group]).

Comment: It seems that the tag with this name was created and removed [at least once before](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2018/8/2). But I haven't found a discussion about this tag on meta.

Comment: Although nobody posted an answer, I'd think that 12 upvotes show sufficient support of your proposal. So perhaps you could retag the single remaining question with this tag (which would then [lead to the removal of the tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/844/how-do-i-delete-an-accidentally-created-tag)).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Done.